# Using Python requests module to fetch URL behind VPN

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib2, vpn

I have few URLs behind my company VPN whose IP I can get. I want to create a connection to those URLs using request module of Python without switching on VPN.

Using Proxy was one of the popular solutions here but I couldn't verify if they work for internal VPN as well.

Suppose the IP address is http://a.b.c.d/ of URL behind VPN.

My Python3 script looks like:

```
import requests 

proxy = "a.b.c.d"

request_data =requests.get("http://api/json", proxies={"http":"http://%s" % proxy})
print(request_data)
```

I'm trying to create connection to http://a.b.c.d/api/json without VPN.

Expected Outcome:
200 (which would denote the connection was made successfully)

I also tried using urllib2 module but without any success.

Python Script:

```
import urllib2

proxy = "a.b.c.d" 

proxies = {"http":"http://%s" % proxy}
url = "http://api/json"

proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxies)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support, urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
print(req)
```

*Script code for both was taken from another answers of stack overflow.*

I might be making mistake in defining the URL but I don't think fixing it would resolve my issue.

The VPN client we have been using is GlobalProtect.

Comment: Are you saying your employer uses Palo Alto GlobalProtect but it's only hiding DNS, not actually working as a firewall —the IP addresses of internal things are publicly accessible? That seems like a major problem for your IT folks...

Comment: By getting IP,  I meant I can run a traceroute on the URL while the VPN is switched on to get them not otherwise. The VPN does act as a firewall and IPs won't be accessible publicly.

Comment: After searching a few github issues , I think there's way we can bypass VPN, global protect in particular. The ticket mentions use of openConnect integrated with GlobalProtect.

The command on macos goes like:
sudo openconnect --protocol=gp {vpn portal} -u user@domain.com

However this solution didn't work as well.